# Error installing artifactory-oss helm chart in openshift

Tags: openshift, artifactory

I am trying to install artifactory oss in a openshift cluster.  I am using this helm chart  https://charts.jfrog.io/artifactory-oss-107.39.4.tgz  (Warning I am very new to openshift etc.. I am on a steep learning curve )

I am running the helm chart as the openshift cluster-admin account

However I am getting this error

```
pods "artifactory-artifactory-nginx-5c66b8c948-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any security context constraint: [provider "anyuid": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider restricted: .spec.securityContext.fsGroup: Invalid value: []int64{107}: 107 is not an allowed group, spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 104: must be in the ranges: [1000970000, 1000979999], spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid
```

I think it is a openshift permissions error .. in that it requires a more permissive security constraint.  However given I am running as cluster-admin I find that a little suprising.

Can anyone offer a suggestion how to resolve this issue and get artifactory-oss running in openshift?

Thanks in advance !

--

Tried passing some options to set the uid and gild..
I tried starting with this

helm upgrade --install artifactory --set artifactory.uid=1001010042,artifactory.gid=1001010042,nginx.uid=1001010042,nginx.gid=1001010042,artifactory.masterKey=${MASTER_KEY},artifactory.joinKey=${JOIN_KEY},artifactory.postgresql.postgresqlPassword=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD --namespace artifactory jfrog/artifactory-oss

The options should have set the uids and gids.. but I still got..  Seems the helm chart ignores efforts to overwrite the values

pods "artifactory-artifactory-nginx-5c66b8c948-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any security context constraint: [provider "anyuid": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider restricted: .spec.securityContext.fsGroup: Invalid value: []int64{107}: 107 is not an allowed group, spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 104: must be in the ranges: [1000930000, 1000939999], spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the [JFrog Artifactory OSS Helm Chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/jfrog/artifactory-oss), its documentation [Installing Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-HelmInstallation=) points out to some prerequisites.

> - When installing Artifactory, you must run the installation as a root user or provide sudo access to a non-root user.
> - [For Helm](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-HelmInstallation=)
>
>   - Create a unique Master Key (Artifactory requires a unique master key) pass it to the template during installation.
>   - Create a secret containing the key. The key in the secret must be named master-key
>     `kubectl create secret generic my-masterkey-secret -n artifactory --from-literal=master-key=${MASTER_KEY}`
>   - make sure to pass the same master key on all future calls to Helm install and Helm upgrade.
>     This means always passing `--set artifactory.masterKey=${MASTER_KEY} (`for the custom master key) or `--set artifactory.masterKeySecretName=my-masterkey-secret` (for the manual secret) and verifying that the contents of the secret remain unchanged.
>   - create a unique join key: By default the chart has one set in the `values.yaml` (`artifactory.joinKey`).
>     However, this  key is for demonstration purposes only and should not be used in a production environment

The point is: it depends on the exact command used to install the Helm Chart.

```
helm upgrade --install artifactory --set artifactory.masterKey=${MASTER_KEY} \
                                   --set artifactory.joinKey=${JOIN_KEY} \
                                   --namespace artifactory jfrog/artifactory
```

As [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70437677/6309), the value for "`runAsUser`" and "`fsGroup`" in `values.yaml` can have an influence on the error message..

> Unlike other installations, Helm Chart configurations are made to the `values.yaml` and are then applied to the `system.yaml`.
>
> Follow these steps to apply the configuration changes.
>
> - Make the changes to `values.yaml`.
> - Run the command.
>   `helm upgrade --install artifactory -n artifactory -f values.yaml`

See [Managing security context constraints](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/authentication/managing-security-context-constraints.html)  for more.

Comment: Thanks for the info..

First thing I tried, running the helm upgrade as root made no different and I got the same error message...

So .. next thing I will try is using the values.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error is not arising from the install itself, but from an OpenShift security "feature" that changes the permitted UID/GID range with each installation.  More info is available [here](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/a-guide-to-openshift-and-uids); personally I have found that it's usually possible to avoid the use of specific UIDs for services entirely by chmod-ing strategically, but perhaps that's not an option for you.